# How can I use Javascript to loop through HTML elements and remove inline attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, attributes

I was working with an online store platform that doesn't provide full editing access to the HTML on page and was looking for a vanilla JS solution to remove various inline styling which I can't remove directly.

I was interested in a reusable function for such a purpose, so that I could use this type of capability on another project later.

Comment: **NOTE: This is an ask-and-answer post**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution involved the creation of a two dimensional array and two helper functions. I hope someone else finds this useful on one of their projects:

### Step 1 - Setup element/node list

The first part of this is to fill your application what elements you want to work with. This nested arrays have two values: the CSS selector for the element in question, and a boolean (true/false) flag to indicate if that element's children should also have their attributes removed.

```
var element_array = [
    ['.selector', true],
    ['.other-selector', false]
];
```

### Step 2: Setup inline attribute array

The next step is to indicate which HTML attributes you want to remove from each element. Each is simply entered into an array:

```
var remove_attributes_array = [
    'style',
    'align',
    'border',
    'cellpadding',
    'cellspacing',
    'width',
    'height'
];
```

### Step 3: Setup helper functions

The helper functions perform the logic of searching through the elements and removing their inline styles.

#### Function 1: `agnostize_element_styles(array);`

This function loops through the element_array variable (array literal from step 1) and executes the second function (which actually removes the attributes). If the 2nd array value is `true`, then that element's children are iterated over and their inline attributes are also removed.

*Function source*

```
function agnostize_element_styles(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var element_list = document.querySelectorAll(array[i][0]);

        for(var i = 0; i < element_list.length; i++)
        {
            inline_html_attributes( element_list[i], remove_attributes_array );

            if( array[i][1] === true && element_list[i].hasChildNodes() ) 
            {
                var child_nodes = element_list[i].querySelectorAll('*');

                for(var i = 0; i < child_nodes.length; i++)
                {
                    inline_html_attributes( child_nodes[i], remove_attributes_array );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Function 2: `inline_html_attributes(element);`

This function accepts an element as an argument, then removes all inline attributes which were specified in step 2's array variable.

*Function source:*

```
function inline_html_attributes(element, attribute_array) {

    for(var i = 0; i < attribute_array.length; i++)
    {
        element.removeAttribute(attribute_array[i]);
    }
}
```

### Step 5: Call Function 1 using the Step 1 array

To make all of this work, simply run the first function (agnostize_element_styles) passing in the two dimensional array from Step 1 as an argument:

`agnostize_element_styles(element_array);`

### View Full Code

```
var element_array = [
    ['.selector', true],
    ['.other-selector', false]
];

var remove_attributes_array = [
    'style',
    'align',
    'border',
    'cellpadding',
    'cellspacing',
    'width',
    'height'
];

function agnostize_element_styles(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var element_list = document.querySelectorAll(array[i][0]);

        for(var i = 0; i < element_list.length; i++)
        {
            inline_html_attributes( element_list[i], remove_attributes_array );

            if( array[i][1] === true && element_list[i].hasChildNodes() ) 
            {
                var child_nodes = element_list[i].querySelectorAll('*');

                for(var i = 0; i < child_nodes.length; i++)
                {
                    inline_html_attributes( child_nodes[i], remove_attributes_array );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function inline_html_attributes(element, attribute_array) {

    for(var i = 0; i < attribute_array.length; i++)
    {
        element.removeAttribute(attribute_array[i]);
    }
}

agnostize_element_styles(element_array);
```

Comment: That's a pretty intense answer for 2 minutes after the question was asked :)

Comment: Lol I wrote it myself so I had already worked out most of it prior to posting. I just wanted to share this since I imagine someone else may have been in my situation (i.e. wanting a non-jquery solution to perform a task like this). You'd be amazed at how often things like this are useful, especially if you work with a CMS/platform that you can't directly edit.

*Side note:* Why would someone downvote this? Seems lame to downvote and not comment, especially when the sample totally works.

Comment: Ah!  Sorry I didn't realise it was an ask-and-answer :)  Nice tho